# sessionStorage is storing everything inside the same array

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, local-storage, session-storage

I have this piece of JS:

```
$('.go-to-bag').click(function () {
var productId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
var productName = $(this).parent().attr('product-name');
var productQty = $(this).prev().val();
var productLWeight = $(this).parent().attr('product-weight');
var productPrice = $(this).parent().attr('product-price');

    var newList = new Object(); 

    if(sessionStorage.newShoppingList) 
    {
        newShoppingList = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('newShoppingList'));
    } else {
        newShoppingList = []
    }

    newShoppingList.push(productId, productName, productQty, productPrice, productLWeight);

    sessionStorage.setItem('newShoppingList', JSON.stringify(newShoppingList));

    var retrievedObject = sessionStorage.getItem('newShoppingList'); 
    console.log('retrievedObject: ', JSON.parse(retrievedObject));

});
```

It's supposed to add items to an object in sessionStorage, like this: 
[image]
Instead, it's giving this: 
[image]

It's was working just fine, and know it doesn't work.
The only difference it's that my colleague was implementing a language feature in php on the main file.

Does anyone has a suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling the function `Array.prototype.push` passing 5 params that will be inserted separately into that array.

### [`Array.prototype.push`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)

[image]

You need to wrap it with curly-brackets

```
                     v
newShoppingList.push({
     productId,
     productName,
     productQty,
     productPrice,
     productLWeight
});
^
```

*The code above will add an object as follow:*

```
{
  "productId": 29,
  "productName": "Chocolote negro",
  "productQty": 1,
  "productPrice": "0.0",
  "productLWeight": "0.00"
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much my friend, you were just right!

Comment: do you have any idea why my key is being printed with the name of the array i've first clicked?

Comment: You're talking about 0, 1, 2, 3...? If so, those are the indexes.

Comment: i want to make sessionStorage.getItem(), in another page. But i don't have exactly a key to call the storage.